# Compare 2 rows in 2 similar tables and return only column names with different values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have 2 table `TblA` and `TblB`. `TblA` has columns `A B C ...Z` and `TblB` also has `A B C D...Z` columns. I want to have the columns' name where `TblA` and `TblB` data differ for a particular row. Assume `column A` is the `primary key` and never changes i.e can perform `join` on `column A`.

Comment: But why do you have two tables with same layout and almost the same data??

Comment: because one table stores the updated data and the other its previous value.

Comment: Is the number of columns really that high (20+)? Can you post what the result should look like? Do you really only want the column names?

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, when comparing a version/default/history table to another, there's no better way to do in in a query than column by column

```
select 
case when a.B!=b.B then 'B' else null end,
case when a.C!=b.C then 'C' else null end,
....(repeat for each column)

from tbla a
left join tblb b
on a.A=b.A
```

Keep in mind that if columns can contain null, `null=anything is null` (not true or false), so you might need to wrap each column in ifnull() to compare

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I have not handled nulls here. You can use a function for your database to handle those.

This is sample query for 3 columns. You can extend it for other columns.

```
          with s1 (A    ,B  ,C) as
          (select 1,22,23 from dual union
           select  2,45,47 from dual union
           select  3,66,    68 from dual
          ),
          t1 (A ,B  ,C) as
          (select 1,23,24 from dual union
           select  2,45,47 from dual union
           select  3,66,    69 from dual
          ),
          chng as(
          select s1.*, case when s1.B = t1.B then '' else 'B'  end as B1 , case when s1.C = t1.C then '' else 'C'  end as C1
          from s1 ,t1
          where s1.A = t1.A
          )
           ,chkChange as(
          select a, (B1||C1) as Changes from chng
          )
          select * from chkChange
          where changes is not null
```

Comment: Mysql does not support WITH.